# How can I group similar records together across sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a macro that helps to group similar records from several sheets (actually 6 sheets with variable n° of records) and put the result in a summary sheet all the values found.

for the example, I have 2 sheets (months). Every sheet has this kind of records. and every sheet has unique records (ColA and ColB combination). But in the other sheets I can find the same ColA ColB combination but with different value in ColC.

#### Sheet 1

```
ColA ColB ColC

AAA 111 2

BBB 111 3

CCC 222 50
```

#### Sheet 2

```
ColA ColB ColC

AAA 111 2

CCC 222 50

DDD 111 20
```

#### Result expected

```
ColA ColB ColC

AAA 111 2,2

BBB 111 3,0

CCC 222 50,50

DDD 111 0,20
```

As you can see, new values may pop up while i'm going through the other sheets, so I need to add them indicating a zero for all the previous months Similar situation is when you find a value in 1st sheet, but it's not present in the other sheets.

I only have few lines of code that only do one part of the job, so any help it's extremely appreciated.

Comment: Okay, what is your question?

Comment: @Sifu, there is no need to be condescending. The question, while not really a question, is obvious enough. The correct question you need to ask the user is, *where is the code you've done so far*? To OP, admittedly, the result you expect makes no sense insofar as merging data goes. Why is `DDD` having a value of `0,20` when there's no `DDD 111 0` anywhere? Also, kindly post your code. We're going to shoot blanks here if we start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below - looks a little bit like a mess but there actually is a method to this madness somewhere. As a final touch and if you want the results to be sorted alphabetically in your destination sheet - you may want to add a sorting routine at the end of the code.

Don't forget to enter your sheet names information in both sections commented before running

```
Sub concat_values()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim wscoll As Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    Set wscoll = New Collection

    'Enter your source sheets names here
    wscoll.Add Worksheets("Sheet1")
    wscoll.Add Worksheets("Sheet2")
    wscoll.Add Worksheets("Sheet3")
    wscoll.Add Worksheets("Sheet4")
    wscoll.Add Worksheets("Sheet5")
    wscoll.Add Worksheets("Sheet6")

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    n = 1

    For Each ws In wscoll

        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Cells

            mykey = cell.Value & "/" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

            If n >= 2 Then
                For j = 1 To n - 1
                    myval = myval & "0,"
                Next j
            End If

            myval = myval & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

            If n <= wscoll.count - 1 Then
                For j = n To wscoll.count - 1
                    myval = myval & ",0"
                Next
            End If

            On Error GoTo ERREUR
            dic.Add mykey, myval
            On Error GoTo 0

            mykey = ""
            myval = ""

        Next cell
        n = n + 1

    Next ws

    i = 1

    'Enter your destination sheet name here
    With Worksheets("DEST")
        For Each k In dic.Keys
            .Range("A" & i).Value = Mid(k, 1, InStr(k, "/") - 1)
            .Range("B" & i).Value = Mid(k, InStr(k, "/") + 1, Len(k))
            .Range("C" & i).Value = dic(k)
            i = i + 1
        Next k
    End With

    Exit Sub

ERREUR:

    count = 1

    For j = 1 To n - 1
        count = InStr(count + 1, dic(mykey), ",")
    Next j

    dic(mykey) = WorksheetFunction.Replace(dic(mykey), count + 1, 1, cell.Offset(0, 2).Value)
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work pretty well. The only thing I need to consider is the format of the destination cells. Switching to text works perfectly